# JSONObject cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: java, classnotfound

I cannot import JSONObject, I thought this was something that came with java and an external jar is not needed, why is it saying it cannot find it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I thought this was something that came with java and an external jar is not needed

**No - `JsonObject` is only in JavaEE**. `JSONObject` isn't included in JavaSE, it needs an external library. You can find it on [github](https://github.com/stleary/JSON-java). However, if you use JavaEE, it is included.

If you are using gradle, add the following to your `build.gradle` file (available in [maven central](https://search.maven.org/#search|gav|1|g%3A"org.json"%20AND%20a%3A"json")):

```
dependencies {
    compile "org.json:json:20171018"
}
```

Comment: But i never had to do this before. I work a lot with JSONObject and JSONArray and I usually just create a new project and everything works

Comment: @code578841441 It is only available in JavaEE, not in JavaSE - and in JavaEE it is lowercased (`JsonObject`)

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the following library in Java SE:
https://jsonp.java.net/

The `JSR 353: Java API for JSON Processing` is only in Java EE by default, not in Java SE.