# Trying to get a child key value from a json object saved in an map-variable in sketchware

Tags: java, android, json

i have the following json as a get response:

```
{
    "global": {
        "name": "Lz Cha0S",
        "uid": xxx,
        "platform": "X1",
        "level": 521,
        "toNextLevelPercent": 31,
        "internalUpdateCount": 22822,
        "bans": {
            "isActive": false,
            "remainingSeconds": 0,
            "last_banReason": "COMPETITIVE_DODGE_COOLDOWN"
        },
        "rank": {
            "rankScore": 4227,
            "rankName": "Gold",
            "rankDiv": 2,
            "rankImg": "https:\/\/api.apexlegendsstatus.com\/assets\/ranks\/gold2.png"
        },
        "battlepass": {
            "level": "-1"
        }
    },
    "realtime": {
        "lobbyState": "open",
        "isOnline": 0,
        "isInGame": 0,
        "canJoin": 0,
        "partyFull": 0,
        "selectedLegend": "Bloodhound"
    },
    "legends": {
        "selected": {
            "LegendName": "Bloodhound",
            "data": [
                {
                    "name": "Kills",
                    "value": 331,
                    "key": "kills"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Beast of the hunt kills",
                    "value": 62,
                    "key": "beast_of_the_hunt_kills"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Season 4 Wins",
                    "value": 20,
                    "key": "wins_season_4"
                }
            ],
            "ImgAssets": {
                "icon": "http:\/\/api.apexlegendsstatus.com\/assets\/icons\/bloodhound.png",
                "banner": "http:\/\/api.apexlegendsstatus.com\/assets\/banners\/bloodhound.jpg"
            }
        },
        "all": {cutted becouse off to much Text...},
    "mozambiquehere_internal": {
        "isNewToDB": false,
        "claimedBy": "-1",
        "APIAccessType": "BASIC",
        "ClusterID": "2",
        "rate_limit": {
            "max_per_second": 3,
            "current_req": "1"
        }
    },
    "total": {
        "kills": {
            "name": "Kills",
            "value": 331
        },
        "beast_of_the_hunt_kills": {
            "name": "Beast of the hunt kills",
            "value": 62
        },
        "wins_season_4": {
            "name": "Season 4 Wins",
            "value": 20
        },
        "kd": {
            "value": -1,
            "name": "KD"
        }
    }
}
```

I saved this json to a map with the skecthware block

`Json [response] to Map [response]`[json to map block](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ah4Aj.png)

Now a want to get the name key with is in the global key, but if i use the block

`Map [response] get key [name]`
[Map get key name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WDzUG.png)

It gives a error that name cannot be found (null exeption)

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.Object.toString()' on a null object reference at com.chaos droid.attack.MainActivity$3.onResponse(MainActivity.java:365) se(MainActivity.java:365) at com.chaosdroid.attack.RequestNetwork er$3$2.run(RequestNetworkController.java:171) at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:

873) at

android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.ja va:99) at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) at android.app.Activity Thread.main(ActivityThread.j ava:6718) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:491) ArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:491)

at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(Zygotel nit.java:858)

END APPLICATION
```

If i use the global key in the get key block it returns the global key as Text

`Map [response] get key [global]`
[get map key global](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0WkTB.png)

returns

`{name=Lz Cha0S, uid=xxx, platform=X1, level=521.0,     toNextLevelPercent=31.0, internalUpdateCount=22822.0,     bans={isActive=false, remainingSeconds=0.0, last_banReason=COMPETITIVE_DODGE_COOLDOWN}, rank={rankScore=4227.0, rankName=Gold, rankDiv=2.0, rankImg=https://api.apexlegendsstatus.com/assets/ranks/gold2.png}, battlepass={level=-1}}`

i tried to save that output to a New map variable but its not a valid json objet so the json to map block is not working.

It looks like the map value can store only one key with value not a child key. When i get the response where i have an error in the get field it returns an error json that looks like this:

`{"Error": "Player not found. Try again?"}`

Here can i get the key succsessful with the same get key block:
`Map [response] get key [global]`
[Get map.key error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0H0cb.png)

i also tried to parse the json with Java in an add source directly block with:

```
JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(result);

String aJsonString = jObject.getString("name");
```

But then i get a sketchware Compiler error that jsonobjet cannot be resolved to a type

```
1. ERROR in /storage/emulated/0/.sketchware/mysc/717/app/src/main/ java/com/chaosdroid/atrack/MainActivity.java (at line 355) String result = response;

Type mismatch: cannot convert from HashMap<String,Object> to String

2. ERROR in /storage/emulated/0/.sketchware/mysc/717/app/src/main/ java/com/chaos droid/attack/MainActivity.java (at line 357) JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(result);

JSONObject cannot be resolved to a type

3. ERROR in /storage/emulated/0/.sketchware/mysc/717/app/src/main/ java/com/chaosdroid/atrack/MainActivity.java (at line 357) JSONObject Object = new JSONObject(result);

JSONObject cannot be resolved to a type

3 problems (3 errors)
```

And i dont know how to import jsonobject into sketchware.

How can a get the child key of global from this json?

**Edit:** (thanks to @Dmytro Kyrychkov)

For sketchware users: you need the full declaration of  the function you want to use because you cant import 
libraries in sketchware. For this example this will working in an add source directly block in sketchware:

```
String jsonStr = strResponse; 
Gson gson = new Gson(); 
HashMap<String, Object> json = gson.fromJson(jsonStr, HashMap.class);
com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap<String, Object> global = (com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap<String, Object>) json.get("global"); 
String name = (String) global.get("name");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get a JSON object child field you should follow its structure during parsing:

```
public static void main(String... args) throws IOException {
    String jsonStr = new String(Files.readAllBytes(PATH_TO_JSON));
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    HashMap<String, Object> json =  gson.fromJson(jsonStr, HashMap.class);
    LinkedTreeMap<String, Object> global = (LinkedTreeMap<String, Object>) json.get("global");
    String name = (String) global.get("name");
    System.out.println(name);
}
```

Output:

```
Lz Cha0S
Process finished with exit code 0
```

I hope it helps you :)

Comment: If i use ur code, i get a Java compiling error in sketchware:  Files cannot be resolved
JSONObject cannot be resolved to a type
JSONObject cannot be resolved to a type
JSONObject cannot be resolved to a type

Comment: @chaosdroid Do you have org.json library? You need to include it or download .jar.
try: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26439675/jsonobject-cannot-be-resolved-to-a-type/26439745) or [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43813670/how-can-i-solve-org-json-simple-jsonobject-cannot-be-resolved?rq=1)

Comment: I am using the mobile IDE sketchware and i think its not possible to include libarys.

Comment: @chaosdroid Could you try the new variant, please?

Comment: Kyrychko's didnt see that you updated your post.thanks, I will try it asap. Currently at work :)

Comment: tried it but get again compiling errors: Files cannot be resolved
LinkedTreeMap cannot be resolved to a type :/ maybe i need to Export my source to Android Studio and complete my work there. It seems that sketchware has nothing an librarys included so its impossible to do what i want. But anyway thanks for your help :)

Comment: okay i think i got the hang of it.  got the first problem solved. I got the error files cannot be resolved to a type becouse i cant import the java.nio library. But instead i can use the full  declaration, String.jsonStr = new 
String(java.nio.file.Files.readAllBytes(strResponse)); this dosent throws the Compiler error

Answer (score 0):

1. Create two map variables, `map1` and `map2`
2. now get your response in `map1`
3. and then use `Json[map:[map1]get kay "global"]` to `map:[map2]]`,

Now you have your JSON data ready to use with `ListMap`, remember that your JSON data is now inside `map2`, so whenever you want to use it remember to get it from `map2`.